# Add restrictions based on joint table values

Tags: java, jpa

I have a table called queue, the model looks like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "queue_id")
private Integer queueId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "location_id", nullable = false)
private Location location;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "queue_room_id", nullable = true)
public QueueRoom queueRoom;

@Override
public Integer getId() {
    return getQueueId();
}

@Override
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.setQueueId(id);
}
```

I am trying to retrieve queues based on a location uuid and queue room uuid. The foreign key on the queue table is the id. I can get queues by location uuid and queues by room uuid separately, but I can't seem to figure out a way to combine both restrictions. Any advise will be appreciated.

```
@Override
public List<Queue> getAllQueuesByLocationAndQueueRoom(String locationUuid, String queueRoomUuid) {
    Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Queue.class, "q");
    //Include/exclude retired queues
    includeVoidedObjects(criteria, false);
    
    Criteria locationCriteria = criteria.createCriteria("location", "ql");
    locationCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("ql.uuid", locationUuid));
    Criteria queueRoomCriteria = criteria.createCriteria("queueRoom", "qr");
    queueRoomCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("qr.uuid", queueRoomUuid));
    
    return (List<Queue>) queueRoomCriteria.list();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the two conditions with and. This is how it looks with JPA JPQL

```
select q from Queue
where q.location.uuid = :location_uuid
and q.queueRoom.uuid = :room_uuid
```

And this would be JPA Criteria API

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Queue> criteria = builder.createQuery(Queue.class);
Root<Queue> queueRoot = criteria.from(Queue.class);
criteria.where(
    builder.and(
        builder.equal(queueRoot.get("location").get("uuid"), location_uuid),
        builder.equal(queueRoot.get("queueRoom").get("uuid"), room_uuid)
    )
);
```